# Detecting lanes in a video using matlab and image processing.

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detect

I am a little bit new to matlab and imageprocessing and I was given a task at my faculty to carry out a project which detects the lanes for a moving car in a video. I tried to use some tutorials on Mathworks and other sites and there were really helpful and I came out with a code that detects lanes in an image and I just want to know how to apply my code on a video as I see it working properly on an image.

and here is my code :

```
img = imread ('test_image.jpg'); 
I = rgb2gray (img); 

%making a gaussian kernel 
sigma = 1 ; %standard deviation of distribution 

kernel = zeros (5,5); %for a 5x5 kernel 
W = 0 ; 
for i = 1:5 
    for j = 1:5 
        sq_dist = (i-3)^2 + (j-3)^2 ; 
        kernel (i,j) = exp (-1*exp(sq_dist)/(2*sigma));
        W = W + kernel (i,j) ; 
    end 
end 
kernenl = kernel/W ;    
%Now we apply the filter to the image 
[m,n]  = size (I) ; 
output = zeros (m,n); 
Im = padarray (I , [2 2]); 
for i=1:m 
    for j=1:n 
    temp = Im (i:i+4 , j:j+4);
    temp = double(temp);
    conv = temp.*kernel; 
    output(i,j) = sum(conv(:)); 
    end 
end 

output = uint8(output);
%--------------Binary image-------------
level = graythresh(output); 
c= im2bw (output,level); 
%---------------------------------------
output2 = edge (c , 'canny',level);

figure (1); 

%Segment out the region of interest
ROI = maskedImage; 
CannyROI = edge (ROI , 'canny',.45);
%----------------------------------

set (gcf, 'Position', get (0,'Screensize')); 
%subplot (141), imshow (I), title ('original image'); 
%subplot (142), imshow (c), title ('Binary image');
%subplot (143), imshow (output2), title ('Canny image');
%subplot (144), imshow (CannyROI), title ('ROI image');

[H ,T ,R] = hough(CannyROI); 
imshow (H,[],'XData',T,'YData',R,'initialMagnification','fit');
xlabel('\theta'), ylabel('\rho'); 
axis on , axis normal, hold on ; 
P = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil (0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2));
y = R(P(:,1));
plot (x,y,'s','color','white');

%Find lines and plot them 
lines = houghlines (CannyROI,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow (img), hold on 
max_len = 0 ; 
for k = 1:length(lines);
    xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
    plot (xy(:,1), xy(:,2), 'LineWidth', 5 , 'Color', 'blue');

%plot beginnings and ends of the lines 
plot (xy(1,1), xy(1,2),'x', 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'yellow');
plot (xy(2,1), xy(2,2),'x', 'LineWidth', 2, 'Color', 'red');

%determine the endpoints of the longest line segment
len = norm(lines(k).point1 - lines(k).point2); 
if (len>max_len)
    max_len = len; 
    xy_long = xy; 
    end 
end
```

and here is the link of the image and the video :

https://github.com/rslim087a/road-video

https://github.com/rslim087a/road-image

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A video is a sequence of images. If your code works on one image, it will likely work on others. I'm sure matlob offers such function: Treat the video as sequence of images and you are done. (What does your question have to do with image processing, and object detection?)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast response. I know well what you are talking about and that's all the more reason why I asked about any method to implement my code on a video as I still know little about matlab and maybe there is a certain way to do this without changing much in the code.

Comment: Check out vision.VideoFileReader (https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.videofilereader-system-object.html). This can read a video and will give you one frame at a time.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me to load the video and play it but I am still not able to proceed with the code applying it on all the video frames.

Answer (score 1):

Basically video processing happens in such a way that video will be converted to video frames (images). So if you need, you can convert your video to video frames and run the code, looping over the folder having the video frames. Change the imread function to get images from video frames folder...

img = imread(path_to_video_frames_folder/*)

Comment: I loaded the video and played it but I am still not able to use the video frames to apply my code on.

Comment: Get the video frames into a folder. After that, use the same logic you used for applying the code for a single image. If you are not comfortable enough, just name the images with a sequential increasing order. And while loading the image from the folder using the code, each and everytime increase the frame number accordingly. By this, you can traverse over all the images..

Comment: I've seen many tutorials on how to extract frames from a video but none of them worked in the end. I loaded my video and it works well but thereafter I cannot make any progression.

Comment: Refer this page, https://www.bogotobogo.com/Matlab/Matlab_Tutorial_Video_Processing_1_Object_Detection_by_Color_Thresholding.php This will help you understanding in frame extraction from video as well as processing each frame individually.